# Pycharm doesn't see change in main.py when starting local server

Tags: python-3.x, django, pycharm

1. I created a project, added main to it for the main page in views and
   about, there are no errors, but the text is not displayed [image: page screenshot] nothing changes at startup, but on the main page it
   writes [image: page screenshot] maybe I'm missing something?
   setting ![settings]([https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hkmx.png]](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2hkmx.png%5D) [image: urls]

[image: page screenshot]

```
from django.contrib import admin
from django.urls import path, include

urlpatterns = [
    path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
    path('', include('main.urls'))
]
```

**setting.py**

```
    # Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    'main',
    'django.contrib.admin',
    'django.contrib.auth',
    'django.contrib.contenttypes',
    'django.contrib.sessions',
    'django.contrib.messages',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles',
```

****views.py in main app****

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("<h4>Hellow i'm main page</h4>")


def about(request):
    return HttpResponse('<h4>About as</h4>')
```

**Urls.py in main app**

```
from django.urls import path
from . import views
urlpatterns = [
    path('', views.index),
    path('about', views.about)
]
```

Comment: Screenshots don't work. Can you share your urls.py and views.py from main app ?

Comment: You can edit your post to add the content of the files in a formatted block

Comment: Please do not post code as images, include the code directly in the post

Comment: sorry it's my first post

Comment: From your image, you apparently have a Django project inside a Django project. You're editing the inner projects urls but are running the outer project...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot the trailing '/'. Don't worry it happened to me plenty of times when i started learning Django. It drove me crazy not knowing where the error was. :D

Urls.py in the main app

```py
path('about/', views.about)
```

Not

```py
path('about', views.about)
```